# Hyper Derivative definition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Following some thoughts in real analysis and in analogy with the classical definition of the derivative
$$
f^\prime(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{f(x+h)-f(x)\over h}
$$
I considered the following hyper-derivative definition:
$$
f^\nabla(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 1}\log_h{f(x\cdot h)\over f(x)}
$$
It is easily proved then that
$$
(f\cdot g)^\nabla = f^\nabla + g^\nabla
$$

I would like please if someone can give some expert opinion in the following:

- Is the hyper derivative definition well defined? or somedody can see a potential problem?
- Can someone provide a geometric interpretation for the hyper derivative definition?

Comment: Can you show the easy proof?

Comment: @gaffney It's just the facr that $$\log_h\frac{f(xh)g(xh)}{f(x)g(x)}=\log_h\frac{\lvert f(xh)\rvert }{\lvert f(x)\rvert}+\log_h\frac{\lvert g(xh)\rvert }{\lvert g(x)\rvert}$$ though I must say that this definition needs $f(x)$ not to change sign in a neighbourhood of $x$.

Comment: Do you have this computed for a few sample functions?

Comment: My proof is the same as the one you gave without the absolute values.

Comment: $$(\sin(x)^\nabla=x\cdot \cot(x)$$

Comment: Looks to be included in the so called [Multiplicative Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_calculus)

Comment: Did the word hyper come from somewhere?

Comment: This operation was studied around 1901-1902 by Robert Edouard Moritz (1868-1940), who called it *quotientiation*, and was rediscovered by Michael Grossman and Robert Katz in the early 1970s, who called it *Non-Newtonian calculus*. Also, both Moritz and Grossman/Katz considered versions for other operations as well. See the references I posted in this [24 December 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4160562).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: as I mention below, this is the slope on a log-log plot. It's been so long since I've been to sci.math.

Comment: @robjohn: I don't think I've looked at a current post in sci.math in over a year, and it's been well over 5 or 6 years since I've even done as much as read through recent thread titles. I treat it more as a library for my own stuff, and many of the posts I wrote there in years past (even as far back as 1999) were primarily intended for me (and others) to use at various future times.

Comment: The link to the 24 December 2005 sci.math post I gave in a previous comment (Nov 7, 2016) no longer works. However, [that post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/1SBs0M7GEfI/m/24BNkPgI9a0J) is still online at the google sci.math archive.

Answer (score 31):

**What is $\boldsymbol{\,f^\nabla(x)}$?**
$$
\begin{align}
f^\nabla(x)
&=\lim_{h\to1}\log_h\left(\frac{f(xh)}{f(x)}\right)\\
&=\lim_{h\to1}\frac{\log(f(xh))-\log(f(x))}{\log(h)}\\
&=\lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{\log(f(x+\delta\,x))-\log(f(x))}{\log(1+\delta)}\\
&=\lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{\delta\,x}{\log(1+\delta)}\,\lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{\log(f(x+\delta\,x))-\log(f(x))}{\delta \,x}\\
&=x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f(x))\\
&=x\,\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}
\end{align}
$$
which is well-defined as long as $\,f'(x)$ exists and $f(x)\ne0$.

Furthermore, if $f'(0)$ exists and $f(0)=0$, then $f^\nabla(0)=1$.

---

**Geometric Interpretation**

Extending the result above,
$$
\begin{align}
f^\nabla(x)
&=x\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\log(f(x))\\
&=\frac{\mathrm{d}\log(f(x))}{\mathrm{d}\log(x)}
\end{align}
$$
which would be the slope of the graph of $f(x)$ in a [log-log plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log%E2%80%93log_plot#Slope_of_a_log.E2.80.93log_plot).

Answer (score 16):

Assuming that $f$ is differentiable in the usual sense in $x$,
$$
f(xh)=f(x)+(h-1)xf'(x)+o(h-1).
$$
If $f(x)\neq 0$, then $ f(xh)/f(x)=1+(h-1)xf'(x)/f(x)+o(h-1)$.
 Moreover, $\ln h=h-1+o(h-1) $, hence
$$
\log_h\frac{f(xh)}{f(x)}=\ln\frac{f(xh)}{f(x)}\cdot (\ln\,h)^{-1}=\frac{(h-1)xf'(x)/f(x)+o(h-1)}{h-1+o(h-1) }=\\
=x\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+o(h-1).
$$
Therefore
$$
f^\nabla(x)=x\cdot (\ln f)'(x).
$$
This yields easily $(f\cdot g)^\nabla = f^\nabla + g^\nabla$ and provides the geometrical meaning in terms of the one of the derivative.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say $f$ is continuous, $x>0$ and $f(x)>0$. Then, you are basically calculating $$\lim_{h\to 1} \frac{\ln f(xh)-\ln f(x)}{\ln h}=\lim_{u:=\ln h\to 0}\frac{\ln f(x\cdot e^u)-\ln f(x)}{u}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln f(e^{u+\ln x})-\ln f(e^{\ln x})}{u}=\frac{d(\ln\circ f\circ\exp)}{dy}(\ln x)$$

So, for $x>0$ and $f(x)\ne 0$, you have that $f^\nabla(x)=g'(\ln x)$, where $g(y)=\ln \lvert f(e^y)\rvert$

Similarly, for $x<0$ and $f(x)\ne0$, then $f^\nabla (x)=g'(\ln x)$, where $g(y)=\ln\lvert f(-e^y)\rvert$.

If $f(x)=0$, then the $f^\nabla$ is not defined. And, clearly, if $f(0)\ne 0$, then $f^\nabla(0)=0$.