# generalization of derivative to ratio

Tags: calculus, derivatives, reference-request

I was solving a problem where I was trying to find the maximum of a particular concave function, to be exact, a discrete function that is obtained when sampling a continuous function on integral values. I found it easier, rather than trying to minimize the difference between two consecutive terms, (analogous to the derivative), to set the ratio of two consecutive terms to be $1$.

I'm interested if my function was continuous, whether I could analogously use this method to find a local maximum, instead of using the standard derivative, using some sort of equivalent that considers the ratio of the function to itself over a tiny area rather than the difference. (and this can be further extended to powers).

This "ratio derivative" when applied to $e^x$, would give a constant value for example, since $e^{( x + \epsilon)}$ and $e^x$ have a constant ratio that does not depend on $x$. When applied to a $y=x$, the ratio of $x$ and $x+\epsilon$ must tend to $1$, in a hyperbolic manner.

I was unable to formulate it in the way the derivative is formulated. Using $f(x+ \epsilon)/f(x)$ and tending $\epsilon$ to $0$ just gives 1 all the time, and using $f(x+c)/f(x)$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant yields the predicted results. But I don't want that, I want the ratio at a point itself, meaning tending $c$ to $0$, just like the definition of the derivative.

I suspect what I'm looking for surely exists, but I can't find the name for it because I don't have much formal training in mathematics. I'd like to know what the ratio analogue to the derivative is formally called, so I may read up on it.

Comment: Related: [Hyper Derivative definition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003656/13130)

Comment: Yes! That's a very similar and intuitive way to define it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, if the function is continuous, then the ratio always converges to $1$. But the speed at which if converges tells you if you're at an extremum. Indeed, if $f$ is differentiable:
$$\frac{f(x+\varepsilon)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(x)+\varepsilon f^\prime(x)+o(\varepsilon)}{f(x)}=1 + \varepsilon \frac {f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}+o(\varepsilon)$$

Thus if we're not at an extremum, the ratio converges to $1$ at linear rate $\varepsilon$. At an extremum, $f^\prime(x)=0$ so the ratio converges to $1$ faster (at rate $o(\varepsilon)$, for instance at rate $\mathcal O(\varepsilon^2)$ if $f$ is twice differentiable).

Finally, note that this formulation is equivalent to looking for extrema of $\ln f$ since $$\frac{d (\ln f)}{dx}(x) = \frac{f^\prime(x)}{f(x)}$$