# Are alternative derivative type operations used or studied in any field?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives

I was dawdling around when I thought of looking into an alternative "derivative" that takes the quotient of nearby function values instead of a difference.

$$\lim _{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f\left(x+h\right)}{f\left(x\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{h}}$$

Which I found equals

$$\large e^{\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}$$

Anyway, my operation probably isn't of any significance, but out of mathematical curiosity, I was wondering if something similar to this is studied or used anywhere.

I found a previous question with something similar, about what they called a "hyperderivative", but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: If we want a function of the form $Ca^x$ to agree with a function $f$ to first order at $x$, we must have $a = e^{f'(x)/f(x)}$, which I suppose is fairly significant.

Comment: Observe also that $e^{f'(x)/f(x)} = e^{\log' f(x)}$. If we write $D = \frac{d}{dx}$, $\exp(x) = e^x$, and $D'$ for your "hyperderivative", we have $D' = \exp \circ D \circ \exp^{-1}$, so that $D'$ is a conjugate of the normal derivative by $\exp$.

Comment: See [generalization of derivative to ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2003656/13130) *AND* [generalization of derivative to ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4575357/13130). See also the references I gave in this [8 October 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/JRN8axz7Zwk/m/zwPb19kriy4J) and in [this 24 December 2005 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/1SBs0M7GEfI/m/24BNkPgI9a0J).

Comment: https://youtu.be/lQ_AdAFVsaM?si=w7IwNf-6zJNV08ZY the geometrical derivative